# What is the __ doing in this snipped? "*{roles[__${roleStat.index}__]}"

Tags: java, thymeleaf

In thymeleaf,

What is the `[__${roleStat.index}__]` part doing?

I understand that this is the array index, but what are the `__` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.pdf) says (on page 26):

> Preprocessed expressions are exactly like normal ones, but appear surrounded by a double underscore symbol (like
>   __${expression}__
>   ).

So it's for preprocessing an expression before it's further used in whatever it's surrounded by.

EDIT: Let's additionally clarify what this does in your scenario (if it wasn't clear, yet). It's processing `${roleStat.index}` to get a literal index number, to *then* use it as the arrays index.

Comment: sorry, i had to escape the underscores so they're not interpreted as bold text markup by the the markdown engine. now it looks like it's supposed to.

Comment: Thanks you Mumpitz!